# tail call optimization javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, optimization

NOTE: This is just for studying and bettering myself. I know of the available sort method for arrays. I'm just trying to get the basics of TCO down.

Currently trying to work on a sort algorithm using recursion. However when I try to process large datasets (+4000 objects), I am still getting a stack overflow error. I'm trying to implement TCO. I'm fairly new to the concept but I think I have the gist of it. However, I'm still receiving a stack overflow error.

```
const sort = (arr, counter) => {
  if (!counter) {
    counter = arr.length - 1;
  }
  for (let n = 1; n <= counter; n++) {
    if(arr[n - 1] < arr[n]) {
      let placeHolder = arr[n];
      arr[n] = arr[n - 1];
      arr[n - 1] = placeHolder;
    }
  }
  counter -= 1;
  return counter === 0 ? arr : sort(arr, counter);
};

function sortRecursive(arr) {
  return sort(arr);
}
```

UPDATE:

I managed to get it working, but I don't quite understand why. I managed to handle 100,000 recursions with no problems. I had to move the boolean that checks if counter is defined. However, I do not quite understand why that made it work.

```
const sort = (arr, counter) => {
  if (!counter) {
    counter = arr.length - 1;
  }
  for (let n = 1; n <= counter; n++) {
    if(arr[n - 1] < arr[n]) {
      let placeHolder = arr[n];
      arr[n] = arr[n - 1];
      arr[n - 1] = placeHolder;
    }
  }
  counter -= 1;
  if (counter === 0) {
    return arr;
  } else {
    return sort(arr, counter);
  }
};

function sortRecursive(arr) {
  return sort(arr, arr.length - 1);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
let firstArr = [];
let secondArr = [];

for (let x = 0; x < 100000; x++) {
  firstArr.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100000));
  secondArr.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100000));
}

sortRecursive(firstArr);
//Array[100000]
```

Comment: What is it that you call TCO ?

Comment: could you give sample in/output?

Comment: @Ced no Array.sort()

Comment: Which JavaScript engine are you using? TCO is probably not actually implemented in the JavaScript engine you are using. You can verify this [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). Notice that it is not in Chrome, Firefox, or any Node.js versions.

Comment: You're implementing bubble sort using recursion? Is this code you plan to use in production? JavaScript isn't defined to provide tail call optimization. Are you using a JS engine that says that it provides TCO?

Comment: @Ced No it doesn't, it bubble sorts the array in descending order.

Comment: to avoid overflow error u can use setTimeout in return statement  but this will make it async func

Comment: I just added some sample output. I don't understand why it's working now though.

Comment: Regarding your test code, whenever you want to generate random integers, use `Math.floor(Math.random()*n)` instead of `Math.ceil(Math.random()*n)`. If you want the range of random integers to start at 1, add 1 to the `Math.floor()` result. This is because `Math.random()` returns a value greater than _or equal to_ 0 and less than 1. So in addition to the values 1...n that you will usually get from `Math.ceil()`, there is also a small but finite chance of getting a 0 result. `Math.floor()` avoids this and is the correct way to generate a random integer.

Answer (score 2):

As you likely know, tail call optimization is a compiler technique that can allow a program to recurse infinitely by not allocating more memory per each recursion call.

Javascript is **not** currently tail call optimized, but the ES2015 standard of the language specification includes TCO. Every time a function calls itself in Javascript, a new stack frame is created, allocating new memory, so it will eventually run out and crash.

There are techniques to avoid this, including [trampolines](http://raganwald.com/2013/03/28/trampolines-in-javascript.html) and not using a recursive loop. But at the moment you can not recursive infinitely in Javascript.

Comment: Got it to work with TCO. Not sure why the changes I made worked though.

Comment: I don't think they did work. See the test case in my answer. It indicates no TCO is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need recursion ( it will never work with 4000+ elems as this exceeds every call stack)?? cant you do:

```
const sort = (arr) => {
     var counter = arr.length;
     while(counter-->0){
       for (let n = 1; n <= counter; n++) {
           if(arr[n - 1] < arr[n]) {
              let placeHolder = arr[n];
              arr[n] = arr[n - 1];
              arr[n - 1] = placeHolder;
           }
        }
     }
     return arr;
}
```

If you want *kind of* recursion, you could use the *qeue* to keep the stack empty (requires passing a callback):

```
setTimeout(sort,0,arr,counter);//instead of sort(arr,counter);
```

By the way, easier and much faster ( because its natively implemented):

```
arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
```

Comment: I managed to get it to work with TCOs. I tested out 100,000 recursions. It's more so to experiment with optimization and memory consumption. I'm mainly trying to understand the concept of TCO. It'll handle massive iterations faster than a for loop.

Comment: @edwin delrio why should TCO be faster than a normal for loop?? Rhinking in assembly, its basically the same..

Comment: TCO faster than a `for` loop? I don't think so. TCO simply converts the tail call into a `goto` to the top of the function after changing any necessary variables. So at best it will be about the same as any other loop structure.

Comment: And at worst, the engine doesn't even implement it, so you're stuck with a Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you *sure* you're getting tail call optimization?

Here's a test with your updated code. The only things I changed are:

1. Added `'use strict';` to put the code in strict mode. Some browsers that support TCO in the future may require strict mode to use TCO.
2. Added `console.trace()` to print the call stack on each `sort()` call.
3. Changed the test array setup to use `Math.floor()` instead of `Math.ceil()` for the reason mentioned in my comment above.
4. Changed the array length to 10.

Open the developer console before running the snippet and observe the call stack traces.

I tested this in the latest versions of Chrome 59.0.3071.109, Firefox 54.0, and Edge 15.15063. The stack traces from all of them show the call stack growing on each call, indicating that there is no tail call optimization.

Just for kicks, I also tried it in Chrome with `length = 100000`. It ran for a very long time, probably a minute or so, and then failed with a stack overflow when the stack reached a depth of about 10257 calls. For comparison, the standard `sort( function( a, b ) { return b - a; } )` completed in about 5 seconds.

Here is a good [article about JavaScript tail call optimization and related topics](http://lucasfcosta.com/2017/05/08/All-About-Recursion-PTC-TCO-and-STC-in-JavaScript.html). One of the things the article mentions is that you can get TCO in node.js by using the `--harmony_tailcalls` command line switch along with `'use strict';`.

```js
'use strict';

const sort = (arr, counter) => {
  console.trace();
  if (!counter) {
    counter = arr.length - 1;
  }
  for (let n = 1; n <= counter; n++) {
    if(arr[n - 1] < arr[n]) {
      let placeHolder = arr[n];
      arr[n] = arr[n - 1];
      arr[n - 1] = placeHolder;
    }
  }
  counter -= 1;
  if (counter === 0) {
    return arr;
  } else {
    return sort(arr, counter);
  }
};

function sortRecursive(arr) {
  return sort(arr, arr.length - 1);
}

let firstArr = [];
let length = 10;

for (let x = 0; x < length; x++) {
  firstArr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * length));
}

console.clear();
sortRecursive(firstArr);
//firstArr.sort( function( a, b ) { return b - a } );
console.log( firstArr );
```